# Mysql using where clause with Binary data type

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I am learning how to encrypt user passwords in my database. I have opted for the SHA-256 hash method using a Salt and the encryption takes place just fine.

I am currently working with a test table on database that only has two fields, here is the create statement.

```
create table test(
  id int auto_increment,
  password binary(70),
  primary key(id))
```

In my php, I use the following code to encrypt my passwords:

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
$userspassword = $_GET['password'];

$salt = "Th!s$a1tis4Test1ng";

$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$userspassword);
$sql = "insert into test (password) values (?)";
if($stmt =  $conn->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$password);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "stored</br>";
}

$stmt->close();
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

then i later try to see if I get any match using the following php:

```
<?php

include 'connection.php';

$id = $_GET['id'];
$userpassword = $_GET['password'];

$salt = "Th!s$a1tis4Test1ng";

$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$userpassword);
$sql = "select id from test where password = ?";
if($stmt =  $conn->prepare($sql)){
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    if($stmt->num_rows() > 0)
        echo "user found";
    else
        echo "not found";
}

$stmt->close();

mysqli_close($conn );
?>
```

Nothing happens, I always get the "Not Found" message.
I even tried matching the passwords directly withing my phpAdmin by retrieving one of the passwords and using a simple select statement to see if it will return any result.

```
select
      id
from
      test
where
      password = 'someEncryptedPassword'
```

No results still, even when I can see that the passwords do match but I get no results. Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Your `$stmt->bind_param("s",$password);` doesn't have to be `$stmt->bind_param(1,$password);` ?

Comment: No @ThiagoAugustusOliveira, you would not use a `'1'` there.

Comment: Why are you using a binary type for the password field? Doesn't SHA-256 create a 64 character string? Surely your field type should be `CHAR(64)` instead.

Comment: @KevinNagurski thanks bro, i changed it from binary to char and its working now. Reason i used binary is that some tutorial I was following said I must use binary because its more efficient or something like that..You can post ur comment as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're comparing a string to a binary object. Change the type of your field to `CHAR(64)` and it should work.

Comment: Thanks bro... much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$password = hash('sha256', $salt.$userpassword);
$sql = "select id from test where BINARY password = ?";
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-op.html